# Using the mouse coordinates to index a matrix

Tags: dynamic, matrix, interactive, locator

I would like to "write" on to a matrix using the mouse.  That is, I would like to use the integer value of Locator coordinates (p) to index a matrix.  Then, if the mouse button is down, write a 1 in that location.  That approach doesn't seem to work since, when attempting to do something like M[[Sequence @@ Round [p]]], the coordinate p is actually a dynamic quantity, which can't be converted to two integer indices by Sequence @@ Round.

Is there any way to do this?  or, Is there an equivalent workaround that gets the same result.  The simplest example would be using the mouse to input a freehand black and white drawing as pixels on a matrix, which could later be subject to image processing algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51952/7339

Answer (score 5):

```
Manipulate[x = ConstantArray[0, 9 {1, 1}];
 Row[{EventHandler[Dynamic[tds = Reverse[Transpose[x]];
     MatrixPlot[tds, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
      ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
      ColorRules -> {1 -> Black, 
        0 -> None}]], {"MouseClicked" :> (pos = 
        Ceiling[MousePosition["Graphics"]];
       x = ReplacePart[x, pos -> 1 - x[[Sequence @@ pos]]];)}], 
   Dynamic@Magnify[MatrixForm[tds], 2]}], {pos, 
  ControlType -> None}, {x, ControlType -> None}, {tds, 
  ControlType -> None}, AppearanceElements -> None, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! A click and drag to fill would be a nice addition :)

Comment: @rm-rf thanks ;)

Comment: And now you're most of the way to a game of minesweeper!