# Checkbox Matrix

Tags: matrix, manipulate, dynamic

Is it possible to create a dynamically changing binary $n 
\times n$ matrix  $A$, which appears to the user as a $n 
\times n$ matrix/table of checkboxes and the user can change the entries of $A$ by checking or unchecking these checkboxes? If yes, what would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying last example in [Manipulate>Neat Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate&lang=en) (also the second example in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1200/125)):

```
Manipulate[
  ArrayPlot[Take[data, n, n]], 
  {{data, RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {20, 20}]}, ControlType -> None}, 
  {{n, 5}, 1, 20, 1}, 
  Dynamic[
    Panel[Grid[Outer[Checkbox[Dynamic[data[[#1, #2]]], {0, 1}] &, Range[n], Range[n]]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Suppose now I would like to use the chosen matrix in following calculations, how would I get further access to the chosen matrix?

Comment: @Thomas, you can use `Manipulate[ArrayPlot[mat=Take[data, n, n]],...]` to hold the chosen matrix in global variable `mat`.

Comment: I am going to need the gist of this. Thank you @kglr